# How to get a permanent image URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, cache, product-images

In Magento 1.9 I get URL of a product image with:

```
$image = $imageHelper->init($product, $imageType)->resize(X, Y);
$imageUrl = $image->toString();
```

It gives me URL like: `http://store.domain/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x75/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/s/msj009t.jpg`

This works, but this URL leads to cached image which is wiped out every time the Magento's image cache is flushed. Then this URL stops to work and I need to generate new URL.

Is there any way how to get a "permanent" image URL which would work even when a cached image is deleted (so it'd regenerate it when it's deleted)?

I have the very same problem even with Magento 2. The code I use there is:

```
$this->imageHelper->init($product, $imageType)->resize(X, Y);
$imageUrl = $this->imageHelper->getUrl();
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I faced the same issue, we need to run `catalog:images:resize` in Magento 2.

Comment: Hey @KhoaTruongDinh, thanks. But I don't get how this command would get me a permanent URL for an image?